# Environment solving error while installing pyfftw in Conda on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, mamba, pyfftw

I am trying to install pyfftw in a Conda environment from the *condo-forge* channel. I get the following output:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyfftw
```

Output:

```
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package _openmp_mutex-5.1-1_gnu requires _libgcc_mutex 0.1 main, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ _openmp_mutex 5.1.*  is installable and it requires
│  └─ _libgcc_mutex 0.1 main, which can be installed;
├─ pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.11.* , which can be installed;
└─ pyfftw is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ pyfftw [0.10.1|0.10.3|...|0.12.0] would require
   │  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.10.1|0.10.3|0.10.4] would require
   │  └─ python 3.4* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.10.1|0.10.3|0.10.4] would require
   │  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw 0.10.4 would require
   │  └─ python 3.6* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.10.4|0.11.0|0.11.1|0.12.0] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.10.4|0.11.0|0.11.1|0.12.0|0.13.0] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.11.1|0.12.0|0.13.0|0.13.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.12.0|0.13.0|0.13.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   ├─ pyfftw [0.12.0|0.13.0|0.13.1] would require
   │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
   └─ pyfftw [0.13.0|0.13.1] would require
      └─ libgcc-ng >=12 , which requires
         └─ _libgcc_mutex 0.1 conda_forge, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

I do not understand the error. Does it mean we need three different Python versions?

What could be a solution to this?

I tried installing conda-libmamba-solver, but without success. The OS is [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) LTS.

Comment: Perhaps there could be a less intrusive way to resolve this; but in the general case, yes, you have to find a combination of these components which does not have incompatibilities.

Comment: All are the other packages in the environment from Conda Forge? Conda Forge doesn't support mixing `defaults` (e.g., `anaconda`) channels with `conda-forge`.

Comment: @merv Thanks. I did a fresh install of all dependencies from conda-forge, and it worked. You can submit this as an answer. This is strange though, what if some packages are not available in conda-forge?

Comment: Added as an answer. Conda Forge is the most comprehensive channel. Other channels with specialized packages (e.g., Bioconda) build against Conda Forge, which makes them compatible. It's mostly just that `defaults` is not compatible. A notable exception is the `pytorch` channel, which builds against `defaults`. While Conda Forge does its own builds of PyTorch, the `pytorch` channel has additional packages and official builds, so if one wants those, they should avoid installing Conda Forge packages in their PyTorch environment. But that is an exceptional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda Forge has [known issues](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels) with mixing packages with `defaults` channel (i.e., Anaconda). Try installing a fresh environment where everything comes from Conda Forge.

```bash
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.11 pyfftw
```

This solves for me without any issues.